# IPhone like menu with qt on symbian

Tags: qt

is it possible to use QStyle to create a menu like the iphone one with qt on symbian?
I want also to add animations.
Below there is an example of what I want.

[image]
<sub>(source: [iphon.fr](http://www.iphon.fr/public/periode2/iphone_menu_full.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use QtQuick (QML) to do such things. It supports animation and kinetic scrolling (flicking).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can handle animation with QStyle, but you can achieve iPhone 'look' with QStyle. Mixing that with your set of custom animated controls, and it may simulate iPhone 'feel'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the UI similar to iPhone, but not exactly,
you can display thumbnails, and preview windo with transparent rect.
list-view also you can customize to your extent but iPhone is Iphone, Symbian is Symbian..
always there will be minor change in UI as well as speed too